# How can I write to a file that is in use by another process in C#?

Tags: c#, .net, file-io, process, file-access

How can I write to a file which is used by another process in C#?

I am able to read the file using `FileShare.ReadWrite`, but it only works for `FileAccess.Read`. Does anyone have a solution?

Comment: A voice in my head tells me that you should not be doing this. Some description of your scenario will help.

Comment: I don't suppose that this is a file you created yourself, using something like `File.Create`?

Answer (score 4):

If the other process has write-locked the file, then there's not much you can do, unless you don't mind closing the other process's handle or killing it.

Comment: Yes, this is correct. And even if *you* don't mind, that other process most certainly does. So **don't do this**.

Answer (score 0):

You should read the file contents to a separate Stream and then the file is released.